# "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql"]

Tags: jboss, wildfly, datasource, mysql-connector

I am trying to add a mysql datasource to my wildfly(Jboss15.0.0) server.
But I encounter the following error:

```
WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "MySqlDS")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "org.wildfly.data-source.MySqlDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]",
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:/MySqlDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]"
    ]
}
09:22:10,385 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "MySqlDS")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql",
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "org.wildfly.data-source.MySqlDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]",
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:/MySqlDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]",
        "org.wildfly.data-source.MySqlDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]"
    ]
}
```

Here is my module.xml:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="mysql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.46-bin.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

and here is my code to set the datasource:

```
    <datasources>
                    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                        <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                        <driver>h2</driver>
                        <security>
                            <user-name>sa</user-name>
                            <password>sa</password>
                        </security>
                    </datasource>
                    <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/onlinestock?characterEncoding=UTF8&amp;useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=GMT%2B8&amp;allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true</connection-url>
                        <driver>mysql</driver>
                        <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                        <pool>
                            <prefill>true</prefill>
                            <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
                            <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
                        </pool>
                        <security>
                            <user-name>root</user-name>
                            <password>root</password>
                        </security>
                    </datasource>
                    <drivers>
                        <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                            <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                        </driver>
                        <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                            <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
                        </driver>
                    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

Why the server can not see my mysql-connector.
the module.xml is under the floder of JBOSS_HOME/..../modules/..../mysql/main

Comment: I have solved the problem with the help with [link]https://synaptiklabs.com/posts/adding-the-mysql-jdbc-driver-into-wildfly/

Answer (score 4):

I change the standalone.xml and it works
set the  tag in this way:

```
<driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```

That's to say I add the  tag and change the content of